# Rstatix: pairwise_chisq_test_against_p must sum to 1

Tags: r, statistics, rstatix

I am trying to use the `pairwise_chisq_test_against_p()` function from the `Rstatix` package. I am doing this for a large dataset, where it mostly works fine, but I get the following error:

> Error in pairwise_chisq_test_against_p(posClinSig, probVec) :
> Make sure that the `p` argument is correctly specified.sum of >probabilities must be 1.

This error seems pretty straightforward, however, when I try `sum(probVec)` I get `[1] 1`

Here are the underlying inputs:

```
posClinSig <- structure(c(Benign = 13L, Pathogenic = 27L, `Uncertain Significance` = 122L
), dim = 3L, dimnames = list(. = c("Benign", "Pathogenic", "Uncertain Significance"
)), class = "table")
probVec<-c(0.160463597779954, 0.627979105452171, 0.211557296767875)
```

I'm not sure if the added context helps, but when I try the same for different data it works fine, see inputs below:

```
posClinSig_Works<-structure(c(Benign = 2L, Pathogenic = 53L, `Uncertain Significance` = 106L
), dim = 3L, dimnames = list(. = c("Benign", "Pathogenic", "Uncertain Significance"
)), class = "table")
probVec_Works <- c(0.161348241247042, 0.625805925079572, 0.212845833673386)
```

I've tried using `str()` to check for differences in data format, but I don't see anything. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or there's some underlying part of `pairwise_chisq_test_against_p()` that's being picky. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I could not replicate your error messages. Both inputs work. What the function does is to check ```sum(p) != 1``` so you can try that with your data. If that happens to be TRUE due to floating point issue, you might want to do ```probVec <- probVec/sum(probVec)```.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried checking ```sum(probVec) != 1``` manually, and it returned ```TRUE```. Unfortunately, ```sum(probVec/sum(probVec)) != 1``` also returns ```TRUE```. Is there anything else to try if it's a floating point problem?